# How to generate random number but exclude current state in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
int state = Random().nextInt(range)+start;
```

Code is working well. But I want to exclude current value of state variable from random. For example my state value is 5, don't give me 5 but others in range. Thanks.

Comment: Well I solve with "if the new value is equals to previous value, try another random until it's different. But this is not an effiency way, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
int x = Random().nextInt(10);
while(x == state) {
  x = Random().nextInt(10);
}
state = x;
```

Comment: Personally, I would `int x = state;` to initialize it, but that's just nitpicking & this works just as well. Upvote

Comment: Please don't create a new `Random` object for every time you are getting a random number. Instead, create e.g. a global variable and reuse the instance.

Comment: This is just the logic, so I'm referring to the solution with the least needed code